# Allow anonymous POST in WCF REST API

Tags: wcf, iis

Developing a set of WCF REST API to interact with a Flutter application.

Calling GETs requests works just file, but while attempting to use POSTs calls I'm facing this error :

```json
{"Message":"Authentication failed","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

This is the request configuration:

```vb
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method:="POST", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="getPopUpdata")>
Function getPopUpdata(data As PopUpStatoDati) As GetResult(Of List(Of GenericCodeValue(Of String)))
```

This issue started when I've enabled `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` within the `web.config` in order to enable the `HttpContext` to upload files to the server via multipart requests.

Also I wasn't facing this issue while developing the APIs on my machine, probably because I wasn't working with `https` nor `IIS` but with `IISExpress`

I've already tried enabling the Anonymous Auth via the IIS configuration as suggested in previous questions, also adding this to the web config:

```xml
<authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

In other answers, I've also found that setting `AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off` within the /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs might resolve the problem, but I don't have such file in my project.

As for now my `web.config` file looks like this

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="6000" />
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="6000" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
    <add key="wcf:serviceHostingEnvironment:useClassicReadEntityBodyMode" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="it-IT" uiCulture="it-IT" />
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding> 
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WebService.App" behaviorConfiguration="WebService.appBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebService.appBehavior" contract="WebService.IApp">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="***/services/App" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebService.appBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>        
        <behavior name="WebService.appBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" maxUrl="4294967295" maxQueryString="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please check the event log for any relevant error messages regarding authentication failures.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions to get to the bottom of this:

- set `<customErrors mode="On" />` to retrieve extra info.
- The web.config is not the only place where authentication can be set, please verify that no auth is set up in code (e.g. oAuth in your global.asax.cs / StartUp.cs / Program.cs).
- get very detailed trace information using trace log: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

Hope this gives some insight in what's going wrong.